# Deleting from a json file

Tags: php, laravel

I have a json file that looks like this

```
    {
        "product_1": {
            "category_1": "Category 1",
            "category_2": "Category 2"
        },
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is when I delete a category I want to remove the `"key":"value"` from the json file.

Here is my code

```
    public function deleteCategory($product, $category)
    {
        $storage = storage_path("/products.json");
        $file = file_get_contents($storage);
        $json = json_decode($file);

        unset($json->$product->$category);

        file_put_contents($storage, json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

        return (array)$json;
    }
```

What happens is when I delete a category it doesn't remove it from the json.

And what I found strange was if I did this `dd(file_put_contents($storage, json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)))` then it would work
but if I only had `file_put_contents($storage, json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))` then it doesn't work. So I'm not sure where
I'm going wrong.

Comment: @TimLewis - the `$product` and `$category` are the values I've passed to that function from `public function deleteCategory($product, $category)` and it doesn't delete either if I do `$json->product->category`

Comment: Can you add the output of `dd($product)` and `dd($category)`? This code `$json->$product->$category` is technically valid, but only if `$category` and `$product` are not Objects. For example, `$product = 'property'; unset($json->$product);`, which would be the same as `unset($json->property)`. You might have to do something like `unset($json->{$product->name}->{$category->name})`, etc etc.

Comment: @TimLewis - for `$product` I get `product_1` and for `$category` I get `category_1`

Comment: So you're essentially calling `unset($json->product_1->category_1)`, which should be valid... Will have to do some local testing to see what's up. Edit: I can't recreate this locally in `php artisan tinker`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0V7d.png. What does `dd($json)` show?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense... Where is `versionLabels` coming from?

Answer (score -1):

Try this given that the $product and $category are keys:

```
public function deleteCategory($product, $category)
{
    $storage = storage_path("/products.json");
    $file = file_get_contents($storage);
    $json = json_decode($file, true);

    unset($json[$product][$category]);

    file_put_contents($storage, json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

    return (array)$json;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I got this error in my dev tools `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`